# the last result of the rules

Tags: mysql, sql

I understand that this question refers to the trivial

so I have two tables(one to many):

1) rules - id, description

2) result - id, rule_id, result of the rule, date

I want get last result fo each rule from second table

Comment: Hope you have tried something... can you show it..?

Comment: yes, I tried, but result was not what expected. group by, inner join, i do thamthing wrong byt can udarstand what

Comment: is the result id unique? or does it start at 1 with a new rule?

Comment: @Auro Each rule is executed many times.
need a query returning last result of each of the rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ru.id, ru.description, re.result_of_the_rule, re.date
    FROM (SELECT rule_id, MAX(date) AS MaxDate
              FROM result
              GROUP BY rule_id) q
        INNER JOIN rules ru
            ON q.rule_id = ru.id
        INNER JOIN result re
            ON q.rule_id = re.rule_id
                AND q.MaxDate = re.date
```

Comment: What if there are no results for a rule?

Comment: @Andomar: Valid question. Based on OP's statement "I want to get last result for each rule from second table" I assumed (perhaps incorrectly) that he was only interested in rules with results.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
SELECT  q.*
    FROM (SELECT ru.*,result.*
              FROM result
               INNER JOIN rules ru
            ON q.rule_id = ru.id
              GROUP BY rule_id order by result.ID Desc) as q;
```